# VNC to MAC but MAC is sleeping

Tags: macos, vnc, vnc-viewer

I assume my my MAC is sleeping if I try and connect with VNC is hangs.  If I happen to be at the MAC console I can move the mouse or keyboard and then the VNC works. Is there a way to trigger a wake up or disable sleeping from the console?

Comment: MAC is not an acronym. It is not rendered in all caps. It is an abbreviation for Macintosh, like the variety of apple fruit. VNC, however, *is* an acronym for **V** irtual **N** etwork **C** omputing.

Comment: I really dont know why some people have to go off topic?  You know what I was asking as is evident on the next answer.  Maybe it would be more to the point to give an answer and not waste time answering like you did.  This is programming related as I need to get to my Apple Macintosh to run XCode.

Comment: furthermore why are there keywords like mac vnc vnc-viewer.  I didnt add them.

Comment: Those tags are intended for programming-related questions about those subjects. You've found a question that indirectly relates to programming, i.e. you want to use VNC to run Xcode, which is something you use for programming. I don't think it's difficult to see why some people think that's a bit of a stretch. If we start allowing *indirectly* programming-related topics, the site will quickly lose focus and it won't be clear to anyone what's on-topic. That said, I'm not sure why this question wasn't *migrated*, rather than closed. [Super User](http://www.superuser.com/) is a good place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you need to enable WOL (Wakeup On Lan) in OSX, see the following for a detailed explanation of what's involved and how to do it.

http://lifehacker.com/348197/access-your-computer-anytime-and-save-energy-with-wake+on+lan

Comment: thank you I really do appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem, hope it works out.